# Mule ESB: GraphTransformerResolver how to replace it properly?

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

With high load and multiple concurrent calls, we are facing `ConcurrentModificationException` in `GraphTransformerResolver`.

I know, that this issue was already fixed in Mule version **4.0.X** but we are using **Mule 3.7.0** and not able to do upgrade at the moment.

So, we think about possible workarounds regarding `ConcurrentModificationException` 
and one as a possible workaround is to replace `GraphTransformerResorver` with our `Custom Transformer Resolver` were the issue will be fixed by us.

So, advice if it is theoretically possible to replace one Resolver with another?
Any other ideas how to fix this issue - also welcome.